# chartist.js: stroke-linecap is extending the stroke beyond the length of the shape in Bar charts

Tags: svg, chartist.js

I'm using chartist.js library in our project. I've a requirement where in I have to display rounded corners for bar charts. I tried by applying **stroke-linecap:round !important;**.But the stroke-linecap CSS property is extending the stroke beyond the length of the shape  in bar charts. 
But I want the rounded corner painted in the range of the length of the shape.
How can i achieve this? Please help.

Comment: reduce the length of the shape by its stroke-width